# intelliJ IDEA 13 error: please select Android SDK

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have installed `Android SDK 22.3` and `JDK 1.7 update 21` on `Win7 x64`. Now I created an empty android application project using `intelliJ 13.0.1` (also use Emulator as target device) and tried to build the project, but encountered the `'Error: Please select Android SDK'`.

So I choose `Emulator` as the `Target Device`, but I could not select my AVD, as there is a `Error: Cannot find any configured Android SDK`.

In the Project Structure, it clearly shows 'Android 4.4.2 platform' as Project SDK. So I am totally confused, don't know how to resolve the issue.

ps. I was upgrading `intelliJ 12.1.2` to `intelliJ 13.0.1`, and all the settings were automatically inherited from 12.1.2 when launching 13.0.1, but it seems not all the settings were exactly copied over to 13.0.1, which is unexpected.

cheers

Comment: Check module SDK, whether it is set to Project SDK or to something else.

Comment: The module SDK was set to Project SDK and then even I changed it to Android 4.4.2 Platform, it still won't compile.

Comment: So the final work around is to add `Add New SDK` for Android SDK again in the `Platform Settings`, which is very interesting.

Comment: It happens sometimes when the SDK is not fully initialized. But now it should stay that way.

Comment: @AndreyMyatlyuk what do you mean by 'SDK is not fully initialized'? Do I need to initialize the SDK manually?

Comment: I mean "initialization" from IntelliJ perspective. When IntellJ parses SDK info and libraries. I would not worry about it.

Comment: Issue can be resolved by doing some changes in the app build.gradle file and sync the project again. More: https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/error-please-select-android-sdk-app-edit-configuration-error-android-studio/

Answer (score 171):

**My Problem:**
"please select Android SDK", But everything is okey :( -> I think one of IntelliJ file was crashed (after blue screen of death)

**My resolution:**

File -> Settings -> Android SDK -> Android SDK Location Edit -> Next, Next (Android SDK is up to date.), Finished

... and crashed file was repaired!

Comment: Worked for Android Studio too

Comment: The problem is still around - here are my similar workaround steps for AS3 on Windows:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45865789/3853712

Comment: You might need to re-import your project as well as re-start Studio in addition to following this answer.

Comment: its actually File -> Settings -> System Settings -> Android SDK :)

Comment: Solved problem after following the steps even though selecting SDK for edit shown a message saying "Nothing to do".

Answer (score 72):

I encountered this error after installing Intellij IDEA Ultimate 14.1 and opening an existing Android project I had created using Android Studio. It turns out I just had to add the Android SDK to my list of SDKs and fix the project/module SDK settings. This is how I did it:

Go to `File -> Project Structure`. Click on the Project tab under Project Settings. Under Project SDK click on `New -> Android SDK`.

[image: Adding new Android SDK]

Now select the existing directory for your Android SDK. In my case it was in this folder:

`C:\Users\<windows username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

Click Ok. A menu pops up asking you to set the Java SDK + Build target. You can either change these or leave it as its defaults and hit Ok. You should now see "Android API XX Platform" in the Project SDK dropdown. Click apply on the bottom. Then go to the Modules tab under Project Settings and click on the folders in the modules listing.

[image: Module List]

For each folder go to the dependencies tab and change the Module SDK to the new Android SDK and click apply. Then click Ok to close the Project Structure dialog.

After doing the above, my project was fixed.

Answer (score 51):

I had same problem once. every things seems right. I restart, delete and invalidate cache of Android studio, rebuild, clean and nothings changed. It is finally solved by click on **Sync Project with Gradle Files** button in android studio 3.0

[image: Sync Project with Gradle Files button]

Comment: I use Android Studio 3.0.1. Click on `Sync Project with Gradle Files` does fix it.

Answer (score 32):

**Delete all android SDKs from Intellij and add them again**.

To do this open project structure, in SDK pane, delete all android SDK, click OK. open project structure and add them again.

Comment: Worked for me: Just cut the path to the SDK, clicked Apply, pasted it back in and Applied again. … Damn buggy Android Studio.

Answer (score 7):

in android 3.1.1 we cant find sync project in tools
so `C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\projectname\.idea\libraries`
remove the files from libraries and sync again

Answer (score 6):

If you can't compile a proyect and you have this message:

[image]

Go to **File** -> **Project Structure**, then go to **Modules** section and select your module app and then select a ***Compile Sdk Version*** and a ***Build Tools Version*** after that click in **OK**.

[image]

Wait until gradle synchronize and ready!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the problem in IntelliJ Idea 14 actually.
My project was working fine on Android Studio.
I decided to continue development on IntelliJ idea.
After import of project, I wasn't successful to RUN it and I got similar error message in Edit Configuration box.
Based on What @Ali said, I deleted all my SDKs and reinstalled them again but didn't work.

I opened "Project Structure">"Platform Settings">SDKs. I found "Build target" of "Android API 21 Platform" is not set. By set it to one of my latest SDK the problem fixed and I could run project without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you did when I also updated from intellij Idea 12 to 13. In my situation, my Android SDK's Build target wasn't recognized properly, it said something like "Not set" in red instead Android 2.2. Even though I chose Android 2.2 and clicked apply and OK, it showed the "Not set" message again when I reopened the project structure dialog.

Then I chose an other version, Android 4.0 this time, clicked apply, then chose Android 2.2 again, clicked apply. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not so common solution but for me **restarting the IDE** worked just fine. I use Android **Studio 2.2.3**.

Answer (score 1):

Check next lines in you app build.gradle file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25       <--- Set exist in local machine sdk version.
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3' <--- Set exist build tools version.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Project structure (Ctrl + Alt + shift + S) -> Platforn settings -> SDKs -> press "Plus" icon
2. Select "Android SDK" and input the SDKs path (for exanple: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk)
3. Apply or OK button
4. Be happy

Answer (score 1):

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart did the trick for me
(which is always a good first try)

Answer (score 1):

You have to Select Build Tool Version from your project setting.

1. Select Project App Folder
2. Press F4 OR Right Click on Project App Folder and open Module
   Settings In The Properties tab select Build Tool Version from List

This will work on my side i hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using android studio then Android SDK is already present it's just IntelliJ Idea is not able to find it, follow these steps to point it to Android SDK-

1. Navigate to **Preferences** (under **Files**)
2. Navigate to **Android SDK** section
3. You will see **Edit** for updating the Android SDK Path, but as its not set in case of IntelliJ you will see the empty path.
4. Click on **Edit** & it will search for some Android SDK. If found simply apply that or it will download a new SDK and will apply.

Now try syncing Gradle again. Hope this works thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a lot like IDEA can't find the Android SDK.

Have restarted the computer after using the Android SDK Installer?

After that, have you started the SDK Manager to install the Android 4.2.2 SDK?

Can you check the Android_SDK_HOME environment variable?

Take into account that the Android SDK Installer just installs a Manager. After that, you **have** to install an SDK (or several).

Also, when you see 'Android 4.4.2 platform' in the Project Structure, that means that the project will ask for that SDK. It doesn't mean that the SDK has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had to add the same android sdk that i used before again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

there is a button by name android monitor on the left bottom of the screen. if u have an issue with sdk   it will show u confugure link.Change the path to your sdk folder. things will work

Comment: if u dont see android monitor directly , go to tools>android>android monitor..in a few secs u must see the button in the left bottom of the screen..when u click it a mini window pops out

Comment: You can edit your answer instead adding a comment. For a better answer, it would be nice if you can put some screenshots so that it give more support for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem once.I solved this by File->Open->other project,then switch this project by this way.

Answer (score -1):

check if you have installed all the add-ons that are necessary. 
Also I recommend you to use a real android phone for debugging. It's better, It's real and faster.

Comment: his specific question was about emulators. Suggesting someone uses a real phone is irrelevant especially since people use emulators to emulate multiple phone types and android runtimes.

Comment: I also wrote what he/she have to check if you didn't notice! I just RECOMMEND that!