# Error: Please select Android SDK in Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools, google-maps-android-api-1

I am using Android Studio 2.0 Beta2, and i am trying to run old project that uses google maps api v1 (package *com.google.android.maps*) as *.jar file. To run this old project i need specify compileSdkVersion older than the last one (23). I used

```
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:17'
```

But i got **Error: Please select  Android SDK** error in Android Studio. How i can run this old project with older compileSdkVersion?

Comment: Google has changed how it used to reference the compile sdk version. Just use `17` there and it should work.

Comment: Any Idea......?

Comment: please refer to this answer. Your problem should be fixed. [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49190823/2980234)

Comment: Related post - [Android Studio: “Please select Android SDK”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34353220/465053)

Comment: Issue can be resolved by doing some changes in the app build.gradle file and sync the project again. More: https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/error-please-select-android-sdk-app-edit-configuration-error-android-studio/

Comment: Read this answer and all you problems will be solved, trust me https://stackoverflow.com/a/50950752/6751183

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Open gradle.buld in your app module
 change versionCode or versionName  and sync.

Comment: Super, it works for me. But I have a doubt how it works. Could you explain?

Comment: its enough to sync project with gradle files

Answer (score 24):

Also just sync the project from the tool bar  [image: refer the image]

Comment: Work for me, THANKS!!

Answer (score 8):

the easiest way is to:

Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files  (Android Studio 3.0.1)

Comment: This answer is definitely underrated!

Comment: Works, but important to mention that it only works when the required Android SDK is installed

Answer (score 4):

With Android Studio 2.1.3, I got this message when trying to launch my app.

I used the Module Settings dialog in AS to select another compile SDK version. Then I went back to the same dialog and chose Google API 17 again.

Then AS accepted the settings and could launch my app.

Really weird, as the contents of the build.gradle file is identical to what it was when I had the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I could fix the problem in my case you need to set the **compileSdkVersion** and the **buildToolsVersion** manually in the android studio. I don't know why the android astudio doesn't recognize the value from gradle.

So the steps are:

File/Project Structure/Flavors/

and set the buildToolsVersion and compileSdkVersion.

**But you need to check, because the android studio puts this value at the end of the gradle file and if you have replicated this variables, the gradle build make an error.** So I make cut and paste in here

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionDevel
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}.${versionDevel}"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
```

and that's it!

Answer (score 2):

It is works for me

[intelliJ IDEA 13 error: please select Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070268/intellij-idea-13-error-please-select-android-sdk)

My Problem: "please select Android SDK", But everything is okey :( -> I think one of IntelliJ file was crashed (after blue screen of death)

My resolution:

File -> Settings -> Android SDK -> Android SDK Location Edit -> Next, Next (Android SDK is up to date.), Finished

... and crashed file was repaired!

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

I just went to my Gradle button on the far right of the screen on the side and refreshed it and it worked for me.