# Android Studio doesn't detect custom SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I'm developing an app to be executed in [Datalogic](http://www.datalogic.com/) devices. I'm following [this](https://datalogic.github.io/quick-start/android-studio.html#android-manifest) guide to set up the environment. I have carried out all the steps, but when I try to run the app, Android Studio is not able to detect the Datalogic SDK and shows this error:

> Error: Please select Android SDK

In `build.gradle`, I have this:

```
 compileSdkVersion 'Datalogic:Datalogic SDK v1:23'
```

as the guide says. Of course I have installed the Datalogic SDK API 23 from SDK Manager and I can use all the Datalogic's classes.

In my app's `Module Settings -> Compile Sdk Version` I have selected the Datalogic's one but still not working. If I build the app with `gradlew assemble` everything works. So, it seems to be something about IDE configuration.

I have also tried to invalidate cache and restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in @rocciax 's answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070268/intellij-idea-13-error-please-select-android-sdk):

```
File -> Settings -> Android SDK -> Android SDK Location Edit -> Next, Next
```

Done!