# Launch app from Android Studio stopped to work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

There is very weird issue... One time I opened my project and noticed that I don't have opportunity to launch app from studio... Triangle sing cover with black color like it disable

[image]

But if I build the apk file and install it with adb command `adb install -r path_to_apk` it does work.

I have already tried to delete and download new android studio, but nothing changed...

And one more, if I am connecting my device and trying to attach debugger to android process so, android studio doesn't see my device as well as virtual device...

What I need to check? It look like some studio configuration broke or I don't know

Fell free to ask

My plugins

[image]

My configuration

[image]

Comment: click the dropdown (left side of the run button) and select `app` module from the list.

Comment: @Maddy Sorry I forgot about it... I switched to app and for now triangle enable , but I have another issue `Please select android SDK` . Added image to the question

Comment: Check your logcat there will be option to setup sdk

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings from file option available in android studio and check for necessary plugins that are required and after that make sure you installed plugins and then check your project.

Comment: I added the image to the question. I did not understand you exactly, what plugins do you mean?

Comment: No, but now I found something new, look at the comment of the question

Comment: are you giving your sdk location in open module settings -> sdk location?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I forgot to switch build module to the app (next to launch triangle you have some options, so you need to choose `app`)

And then I got sdk location issue

I fixed it with help of this answer

[intelliJ IDEA 13 error: please select Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070268/intellij-idea-13-error-please-select-android-sdk)

My Problem: "please select Android SDK", But everything is okey :( -> I think one of IntelliJ file was crashed (after blue screen of death)

My resolution:

File -> Settings -> Android SDK -> Android SDK Location Edit -> Next, Next (Android SDK is up to date.), Finished

... and crashed file was repaired!

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem "Error: Please select Android SDK" can sometimes happen with Android Studio 3.0, when downloading new build tools.

A temporary workaround is to change the `versionCode` or `versionName` in the app/build.gradle, then do a gradle sync, then change it back and gradle sync. See: 
[Error: Please select Android SDK in Android Studio 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273385/error-please-select-android-sdk-in-android-studio-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue is that `build.gradle` could have the wrong platform version for `targetSdkVersion`.  It might not be picking up the latest Manifest file.

> Please select Android SDK

Is **not** being reported because it cannot find the SDK, but rather because it cannot find the platform version it needs from `build.gradle`.